# Detect Symbian OS devices with Javascript or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, symbian

I'm trying to optimize a website for Symbian OS, and I'm using media queries, however, Symbian OS doesn't recognize them, so I was wondering is there a way to detect if I'm viewing website from Symbian device and load specific CSS for it?

Comment: Have you tried checking browserstrings? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
if (/SymbianOS/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
    // Symbian OS specific code here
}
```

PHP:

```
if (preg_match('/SymbianOS/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="symbian.css" />';
}
```

Comment: At least in my Symbian Nokia 500, preg match should be done against /Symbian/, not /SymbianOS/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but this could work. It enables media queries in browsers that don't support them natively.

```
https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond
```